# Number Format for Input Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to know, how I can reproduce something like this:
[image: Number with dots]

I draw this by myself, but I saw it already a couple of times on websites, that the dots separate numbers (like text from placeholder attribute). Unfortunately, I forgot where I saw it, so I cannot analyze the code to check how they did it.
The challenge is, that the dots need to by shown, the cursor should jump behind the next dot when three numbers were entered and the dots or any spaces should not be submitted, when I submit a form with this field. The post data should be in this case "123456789".

I tried already to google these case, but I found only solutions where the entered value is replaced with a new value, which contains the dots.

Does anyone now how I can archive this?
Is it achievable with JS or pure CSS?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: You are looking for "input masking."

Comment: Well if I was to develop this I would use a fixed size font, use a masked edit component substituting the 3 number separator by space and then use an event in on-change to draw the point. But the real question is... why so much work just because of dots opacity ? I really think this doesn't pay-off.

Comment: @Mathletics Thanks. I'll have a look into it.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira It is not about the opacity. It was the example which I remember. The main point is, that I want to have separation which will not be submitted via the form

Comment: oh... that's simple... and I downvoted the now deleted answer wrongly. There are plenty of js projects that do that. This is the one I use: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
search for: javascript masked edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some components that do that task:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/

https://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/

https://github.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?l_FGl9aS

Comment: I downvoted the now deleted answer wrongly. A comment in the question clarified. I recommend the old author to repost the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. The problem is, that it does not honor one of my challenges. I want to have the separation only in the design. When I submit the form, the delimiters should not be posted which is actually happening. I am creating an add-on script (tampermonkey) for an existing site. I don't want to destroy the already existing validation of the filed, which is shown outside of the input field. EIDT: I used the first of your suggestions

Comment: jquery mask plugin has a .cleanval method, isn't that enough ?

Comment: There is no out of the box solution. I will now overlay another input field above of the original one, will change the font color of the original to white and will use the cleanVal()-Function to put the clean value in the original field. So I can accept your solution. Thank you very much for your help.